# ReactJS + Webpack: Why Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../media/interiorTest.jpg"?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, reactjs

I have a Webpack running with ReactJS, and I am attempting to grab an image and display it but getting an error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../media/interiorTest.jpg"`

And here is what I tried:

```
  <div>
    <img src={require("../media/interiorTest.jpg")}/>
  </div>
```

And the directory tree is (I am trying to fetch `interiorTest.jpg` from `home-page.js`):

[image]

And my `webpack.config.js` is:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env':{ 'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') } }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: { warnings: false },
      output: {comments: false },
      mangle: false,
      sourcemap: false,
      minimize: true,
      mangle: { except: ['$super', '$', 'exports', 'require', '$q', '$ocLazyLoad'] }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('src/public/stylesheets/app.css', {
      allChunks: true
    })
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: ../ would take you just into `components` folder.. so make it `../../public/media`. Or if the public is really public you should just use plain old `src="/media/interiorTest.jpg"`

Comment: @Hardy Tried the first but got the error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../../public/media/interiorTest.jpg"` and when I tried the second suggestion without the src={require()} and just src="", I got `GET http://localhost:8080/media/interiorTest.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @Hardy Please let me know if you've seen my last comment

Comment: Did you forget to paste your loader definition matching jpg?

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen No the webpack.config.js is exactly how I'm using. Sorry but what do you mean by pasting loader definition matching jog?

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen Just checking in to see if you've seen my last comment. Please let me know

Comment: @LyManeug Try changing the src to `src="/src/public/media/interiorTest.jpg"`, It should work since your contentBase is the parent directory of `src`

Comment: @RandomUser Wow Thank you so much! Finally worked! Please make the answer so I can accept it. Sorry but what do you mean contentBase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the code in `webpack.config.js` and the screenshot you included, Your directory structure looks like

```
app/
    src/
         actions/
         components/
         ...
         public/
```

And in `webpack.config.js` you have this code

```
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  },
```

**contentBase** property defines the directory from where files will be loaded when the server is running, And since you have set it as `'./'`, It means the files/data will be loaded from the `app` directory.

And that's the reason to link files from `public` directory you have to include `/src/public` in path as well, something like `src="/src/public/folder/where/image/is-located/image.jpg"`

In this case

```
  <div>
    <img src="/src/public/media/interiorTest.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
```

**Note**

- Usually the code is divided into two folders, `src` to store the code you're working on and `public` for webpack to store the compiled code and for static assets. And we just set `/public` as the `contentBase`.

  It will be worth your time to do some research regarding directory structure for react and javascript applications
- Its good to have `alt=""` for  images, Just enter the alt text as it best describes the image.

Comment: Wow you are seriously the realest! Thank you ton! Learned so much. Accepted the answer and upvoted. Could you please take a look at this as well? In need of your expertise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423965/reactjs-how-to-fix-an-element-to-its-current-position-despite-rendering-of-new