# ReactJS: How to fix an element to its current position despite rendering of new element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have `<h1/>` and `<input/>` elements, and once a text is inputted, a `<button/>` appears/renders

Comment: This is more of a HTML, CSS issue, You can just try placing the `<h1> and <input>` within a div and that might help a little.. but to get the desired results you might have to use css as well. you can checkout this https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/55759/ and see if it helps.

Comment: @RandomUser tried with wrapping them in divs but no go still, and tried different CSS and had no luck...

Comment: Change `<div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>` to `<div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center'}}>`

I changed the `flexDirection` to `column`

Comment: @RandomUser but I am trying to align them horizontally in a row

Comment: Can you upload screenshots of before button and after button screen?

Comment: give button `position: absolute` and place it wherever you please

Comment: @marzelin is right, we have to use `position: absolute` if we want to control its position. updated the answer, see Edit 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you might have to make some changes depending on your entire HTML structure and CSS styles, you could do

```
<div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center'}}>

    <div>
        <h1>Do Not Move Me</h1>
        <input
        placeholder='Enter Name'
        onChange={this._displayButton}
        value={this.state.nameText}
        />
    </div>

    <div>
    {this.state.textEntered ?
        <button
        type="submit"
        />
        : null
    }
    </div>

</div>
```

The main change i made is changed **flexDirection** from `row` to `column`, This makes the div children/sub divs appear below each other instead of appearing beside each other.

Edit:

```
<div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'flex-start'}}>
```

added `justifyContent` property.

### Edit 2:

```
<div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

    <h1>Do Not Move Me</h1>

    <div style={{ position: 'relative', marginLeft: 20 }}>

        <input
        placeholder='Enter Name'
        onChange={this._displayButton}
        value={this.state.nameText}
        />
        {this.state.textEntered ?
            <button type="submit" style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '-10px', right: '-10px', borderRadius: '50%', height: 40, width: 40, backgroundColor: '#881587', border: 'none' }} /> : null
        }

    </div>

</div>
```

You have to edit the `button` styles to make it look the way you want.

Comment: but styling the button as such won't move the other elements anymore?

Comment: No, because `<div style={{ position: 'relative', marginLeft: 20 }}>` has its position set to `relative` and `button` is inside that div and its position is set to `absolute` so you can style button however you want and its position will be `constrained` to its parent div.. but you're free to play with `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` and other styles to make it appear wherever you want and look however you want.

Comment: thank you so much! Worked like a charm. You never fail. Just another quickie, to make it dynamically reposition depending on the browser size, should I put the `top`, `left` etc. as in % rather than px? Accepted the answer and upvoted by the way of course

Comment: Actually I tried it and is a no go. How can I position it so that it moves relative the window width size and do not go over the screen and disappear when minimized?

Comment: It should move relative to window and its parent div size, Using `px` would be best here, also can you show screenshots of the issues happening now?

Comment: got it to work beautifully! Thank you so much RandomUser. Another question if you don't mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39442419/reactjs-is-there-a-way-to-trigger-a-method-by-pressing-the-enter-key-inside