# ReactJS - Is there a way to trigger a method by pressing the 'Enter' key inside <input/>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Using only `onChange` and value and while focused inside a `<input/>`, preferably without jQuery, is there a way to trigger a method by pressing the 'Enter' key? Because, would only want the user to press 'Enter' key in order to update the `name` string state.

Here is the code:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
    }
  }

  textChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value,
    })
  }

  //Would like to trigger this once 'Enter' key is pressed while focused inside `<input/>`
  enterPressed() {
    var name = this.state.name;
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <input
          placeholder='Enter name'
          onChange={this.textChange.bind(this)}
          value={this.state.name}
        />
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What you can do is use React's key events like so:

```
<input
    placeholder='Enter name'
    onChange={this.textChange.bind(this)}
    value={this.state.name} 
    onKeyPress={this.enterPressed.bind(this)}
/>
```

Now, to detect enter key, change the `enterPressed` function to:

```
enterPressed(event) {
    var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if(code === 13) { //13 is the enter keycode
        //Do stuff in here
    } 
}
```

So what this does is add an event listener to the input element. See [React's Keyboard Events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#keyboard-events). The function `enterPressed` is then triggered on event, and now `enterPressed` detects the key code, and if it's 13, do some things.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rn55o9xm/1/) demonstrating the event.

---

**Note:** The `onKeyPress` and `onKeyDown` events trigger instantaneously on user press. You can use `onKeyUp` to combat this.

Comment: What do event.keyCode || event.which do?

Comment: @LyManeug Actually, it's browser dependent, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which). It's a good thing to have in case a browser doesn't support `keyCode` or `which`. `||` just selects an option based on if any others are null or undefined/unsupported, basically a fallback.

Comment: Just to clarify, should `onKeyUp` up should be used instead of `onKeyPress`? Confused as to which one is the right one to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but what do you mean by go back though?

Comment: @LyManeug I mean to stop interaction. Basically down and press go as soon as enter is pressed, up goes when they lift the key

Comment: @LyManeug I had a problem with the code, forgot to `bind(this)`; I updated the answer with a test live example

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification and example! Really appreciate it. Working beautifully!

Comment: No problem @LyManeug!

Comment: One more quick question if you don't mind. If I would like to link the a button to the same method as the enterPress(event), how would I determine if the button triggered it or not. For example, would like to do something like `if(code === 13 || //button triggered it)`?

Comment: @LyManeug I put [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rn55o9xm/2/) together by giving an ID. It should work

Comment: from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43418287/7227940 they are deprecated @Andrew Li

Answer (score 7):

Use `onKeyPress` and the resulting event object's `key` property, which is normalised cross-browser for you by React:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      name: ''
    }
  },
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value})
  },
  handleKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      alert('Enter pressed')
    }
  },
  render() {
    return <input
      placeholder='Enter name'
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
      value={this.state.name}
    />
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#app'))

</script>
```

Comment: If I would like to link the a button to the same method as the handleKeyPress(e), how would I determine if the button triggered it or not. For example, would like to do something like `if(e.key === 'Enter' || //button triggered it)`?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the `render()` for the UI you're trying to create? The easiest way to do this is to have a separate `onClick` for the button and call another method, and to have the text input's `onKeyPress` also call this other method when `Enter` is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a onKeyPress to your input and make it equal the function you want to execute . You would just need to make sure the key pressed was the enter key using the event that is passed to the function as an argument

Unfortunately can't just use the onchange method alone to get this result

Comment: Sorry but before I accept the answer and upvote, could you show an example, especially how to determine if key pressed was the enter key?

Answer (score 1):

here is an example for using onpress event according to your case:

```
handleKeyPress(e) {
    if(e.key === 'Enter' || e.which === 13){
      console.log('enter key pressed');
      // call your method here
     }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <input
          placeholder='Enter name'
          onChange={this.textChange}
          onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
          value={this.state.name}
        />
    )
  }
```

when you press any key inside the input field, it calls the function handleKeyPress which is receiving an event. From that event you are checking if the pressed key is Enter key or not. Also you can use the value of input. e.g. `let value = e.target.value;`

Answer (score 0):

You just simply fire a function like this,

```
<input type="text"
 onKeyPress={(event) => {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (key === 13) {
        // perform your Logic on "enter" button 
        console.log("Enter Button has been clicked")
    }
}}
/>;
```